# Need help creating a batch that outputs cmd output - Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

In my code below, I am trying to figure out how to make a batch file that outputs all tree directories (i.e. the output in cmd)

```
md D:\Outputs\%USERNAME%\
cd D:\Outputs\%USERNAME%\
tree C: /f 
*output* >> tree.txt
```

The code I've put above just outputs ridiculous amounts of code - longer than doing the same command in CMD alone.

(And yes I know I put D: and C: as different drives. The D: runs from a USB plugged into the D: and my C: is my main storage drive.)

1. Can you tell me how to make it so that it outputs roughly the same amount of output as CMD does (I suspect a different directory).
2. Can you also tell me how to put the output into a text file (i.e. What command do i use where it says * output *?)

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: What do you mean, "longer than doing the same command in `CMD` alone"? What command are you doing in `CMD`, _exactly_, and what are you _expecting_ to see?

Comment: no "command" for `*output*` - it's just `tree C: /f >>tree.txt` See [SS64 - Redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) for more explanation

Comment: @Stephan Yes. Only problem is that it will not pipe Unicode characters.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are a few options.
this one does not support Unicode.

```
md D:\Outputs\%USERNAME%\
cd D:\Outputs\%USERNAME%\
tree /f C:\ > logfile.txt
```

This one does support Unicode, because it outputs to clipboard. But requires you to manually paste it.

```
tree /f C:\ |clip
```

Then open Notepad.exe and CTRL+V or right click and paste.

Finally you could pipe ascii then covert to Unicode like this in a script...

```
md D:\Outputs\%USERNAME%\
cd D:\Outputs\%USERNAME%\
tree /f C:\ > a.txt
cmd /u /c type a.txt > output.txt
del /Q a.txt
```

Then just open manually or via the same script by adding this at the very bottom.

```
notepad output.txt
```

Finally, I would suggest you check if directory exists before attempting to create it each time, just makes more sense and causes less errors.

```
if not exist "C:\Outputs\%USERNAME%" mkdir "C:\Outputs\%USERNAME%"
cd D:\Outputs\%USERNAME%\
tree /f C:\ > a.txt
cmd /u /c type a.txt > output.txt
del /Q a.txt
```

Comment: You should add a trailing back slash, `TREE/F C:\>a.txt` otherwise you're unlikely to get a full listing rooted at C: